# Does spring-data-neo4j have a beforeSave method?

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

How can I execute some code just before an entity is saved?

```
@NodeEntity
public class Person {

    @Transient
    String password
    String passwordHash

    public void beforeSave() { // I made this method name up.
        if (password != null && !password.isEmpty()) {
            passwordHash = AuthenticationService.encodePassword(email, password);
            password = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Do I need to use AspectJ or is there a simpler way using an annotation?

I've added the following dependencies:

```
compile("org.springframework.data:spring-data-neo4j:3.3.0.RELEASE")
compile("org.springframework.data:spring-data-neo4j-rest:3.3.0.RELEASE")
```

Comment: Which version of SDN are you asking about?

Comment: @Luanne, I've edited the question and added the dependencies I'm using.

Comment: @Spider you can have a look to [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30106772/sdn-beforesaveeventt-capture-events-before-save-entities-t), you could see a SDN beforeSave event example.

Answer (score 0):

In SDN3, you have BeforeSave ApplicationEvents like in the rest of the Spring Data projects.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-neo4j/docs/3.3.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#lifecycle_events

Comment: thanks for the answer. So, does this mean there is so simple interface I can implement that adds a beforeSave() event to the actual bean? Do we have to listen for a beforeSave event separately when we set up Neo4J? Seems a bit tedious, and separating the logic from the concern. What are your thoughts?