# SDN BeforeSaveEvent<T> capture events before save entities != T

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

Currently I've centralized the `Id` creation of each NodeEntity in a BeforeSave Application Event. Something like that:

```
   @Inject
   IdentifierFactory identifierFactory;

   @Bean
   ApplicationListener<BeforeSaveEvent> beforeSaveEventApplicationListener() {
      return new ApplicationListener<BeforeSaveEvent>() {
         @Override
         public void onApplicationEvent(BeforeSaveEvent event) {
            if (event.getEntity() instanceof IdentifiableEntity) {
               IdentifiableEntity entity = (IdentifiableEntity) event.getEntity();
               if (entity.getId() == null) entity.setId(identifierFactory.generateId());
            }
         }
      };
```

This works fine.

However, In my graph model I have identifiable entities (with id attribute, implementing `IdentififableEntity` interface) and others non-identifiables. What I'm trying to do is capturing the before save event only if the entity is identifiable, in order to avoid the instanceof/casting:

```
if (event.getEntity() instanceof IdentifiableEntity)
IdentifiableEntity entity = (IdentifiableEntity) event.getEntity();
```

I've tried the next, but it doesn't work (the before save event continue capturing non-identifiable entities):

```
   @Bean
   ApplicationListener<BeforeSaveEvent<IdentifiableEntity>> beforeSaveEventApplicationListener() {
      return new ApplicationListener<BeforeSaveEvent<IdentifiableEntity>>() {
         @Override
         public void onApplicationEvent(BeforeSaveEvent<IdentifiableEntity> event) {
            if (event.getEntity() == null) event.getEntity().setId(identifierFactory.generateId());
         }
      };
   }
```

I'm not really sure if I can do that. I've also tried specifying a particular `class` (for example `BeforeSaveEvent<User>`) instead of an `interface` and I've the same problem, the event also captures other entities != `User`.

Can anyone clarify if what I'm trying to do is possible with `spring-data-neo4j` (version `3.3.0.RELEASE`) and if so, an example of how can do that.

Thanks in advance.